# Find and for loop

Tags: shell-script, find, for

Trying to do a mass convert from M4A to OGG in a large music collection, I have:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `find /home/family/Music -name *.m4a -print0`
   #do ffmpeg -i "$i" -acodec libvorbis -aq 6 -vn -ac 2 "$i.ogg";
   do echo $i
done
```

All of the files will have spaces in their names, the output for the above shows a single file like this:

```
/home/family/Music/The
Kooks/Inside
In
_
Inside
Out/06
You
Don't
Love
Me.m4a
```

Every space marks a new line, I thought `-print0` would fix this?

Comment: Please don't cross-post: http://askubuntu.com/q/531115/158442

Comment: SO has a very good answer about [how to loop over find results](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7039579/3076724) (not that it's really needed here)

Answer (score 4):

Use `while` loop together with `read -d '' -r`:

```
find /home/family/Music -name '*.m4a' -print0 | while read -d '' -r file; do
   echo "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can move the external loop into an "internal" loop and obviate word-splitting issues like so:

```
find /home/family/Music -name '*.m4a' -exec \
sh -c 'for i; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -acodec libvorbis -aq 6 -vn -ac 2 "$i.ogg"; done' sh {} +
```

Notice that `-print0` is no longer needed
Additionally, you need to quote `*.m4a` to avoid accidental glob expansion by shell